# Magento 1x: What happens if two modules from different vendors customize a single template?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, template, conflict

How magento handles conflicts?
What if I install two separate modules from different vendors where both of them customize a single template, let's say `checkout/succes.phtml`?
I am expecting answers for `magento 1.9.2.4`

Comment: refer https://www.quora.com/How-magento-reacts-when-multiple-modules-override-the-same-core-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When multiple modules override a same file, Magento usually takes the one which comes first alphabetically according to  Namespace_Modulename

The modules are collected in the following order:

- Mage_All (collection of vital modules)
- Other Mage_* modules
- 3rd party modules